# Implementing Simple Inheritance in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, prototypal-inheritance

I have been using the [John Resig javascript  class implementation](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/) in my web apps, but the tests shows it is really slow. I really find it useful for the way of extending objects, and the benefits got from having a better code and less redundancy.

In some post was explained that it was slow because of the how the `_super` method is handled.
Since `super` is Java style, and most of time I develop in PHP, I made my own version of Resig implementation using the `parent::` style (used in PHP), with the aim to make this faster. Here it is:

```
(function () {
  this.Class = function () {
  };
  Class.extend = function extend(prop) {
    var prototype = new this();
    prototype.parent = this.prototype;

    for (var name in prop) {
      prototype[name] = prop[name];
    }

    function Class() {
      this.construct.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    Class.prototype = prototype;
    Class.prototype.constructor = Class;
    Class.extend = extend;

    return Class;
  };
}) ();
```

Case of use:

```
var Person = Class.extend({
  construct: function (name) {
    this.name = name;

  },
  say: function () {
    console.log('I am person: '+this.name);
  },

});

var Student = Person.extend({
  construct: function (name, mark) {
    this.parent.construct.call(this, name);
    this.mark = 5;
  },
  say: function () {
    this.parent.say();

    console.log('And a student');
  },
  getMark: function(){
   console.log(this.mark);
  }
});

var me = new Student('Alban');
me.say();
me.getMark();
console.log(me instanceof Person);
console.log(me instanceof Student);
```

Any opinion about this? I this way fast? What about correctness?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for [a code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Yes it so, if you can move it to the right section would be better

Comment: @Quentin I moved it here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/77592/implementing-simple-and-fast-inheritance-in-javascript. What do you think about?

Answer (score -1):

On a first sight, this looks not bad :), but I think the implementation done by coffeescript is currently one of the most sophisticated:

```
class Person
  walk: ->
    return

class myPerson extends Person
  constructor: ->
    super
```

translates to this:

```
var Person, myPerson,
  __hasProp = {}.hasOwnProperty,
  __extends = function(child, parent) { for (var key in parent) { if (__hasProp.call(parent, key)) child[key] = parent[key]; } function ctor() { this.constructor = child; } ctor.prototype = parent.prototype; child.prototype = new ctor(); child.__super__ = parent.prototype; return child; };

Person = (function() {
  function Person() {}

  Person.prototype.walk = function() {};

  return Person;

})();

myPerson = (function(_super) {
  __extends(myPerson, _super);

  function myPerson() {
    myPerson.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
  }

  return myPerson;

})(Person);
```

It is fast, clean and does ownProperty checking.